# How to pre-process image using tensorflow lite support library on Android?

Tags: android, tensorflow, kotlin, tensorflow-lite, image-preprocessing

I have following code in place which pass camera taken image as `Bitmap` to be feeded in to Machine learning model.

**CameraFragment.kt**

```
private lateinit var photo: Bitmap

private fun takePhoto() {
    val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return
    imageCapture.takePicture(cameraExecutor, object :
        ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
        override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
            super.onCaptureSuccess(image)
            photo = imageProxyToBitmap(image)
        }
    })
}


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    ...
    val ml = MachineLearning()
    ml.downloadModel()
    val prediction = ml.predict(photo)
    ...
}
```

**MachineLearning.kt**

```
fun predict(photo: Bitmap): Boolean {

    // image pre-processing

    ...

}


private fun downloadeModel() {
    val conditions = CustomModelDownloadConditions.Builder()
        .requireWifi()
        .build()
    FirebaseModelDownloader.getInstance()
        .getModel("model-name", DownloadType.LOCAL_MODEL_UPDATE_IN_BACKGROUND, conditions)
        .addOnCompleteListener { customModel ->

            customModel.addOnSuccessListener { model: CustomModel? ->
                modelFile = model?.file!!
                interpreter = Interpreter(modelFile)
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Log.d(TAG, "Internet is necessary to download the model!")
        }
}
```

But I am not sure how to do the image pre-processing. According to [this codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/recognize-flowers-with-tensorflow-on-android/#6) `ImageProcessor` class should be used for this. But I am not sure how to do this?

Given below is analogous Python code to test the model using single image

```
def testing_tflite_model(sample_type, quantized):
    converted_model = "models/converted/model.tflite"
    if quantized:
        converted_model = "models/converted/model-quantized.tflite"

    bad_image_path = "..."
    good_image_path = "..."
    img = io.imread(bad)

    if sample_type == "good":
        img = io.imread(good_image_path)

    resized = resize(img, (106, 106)).astype('float32')
    test_image = np.expand_dims(resized, axis=0)
    normalized_image = test_image - 0.5

    prediction = run_tflite_model(converted_model, normalized_image)
    if prediction == 1:
        print("Bad")
    else:
        print("Good")
```

My try so far:

```
val imageProcessor = ImageProcessor.Builder()
        .add(ResizeOp(106, 106, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR))
        .build()
```

But how to normalize the image as in python code?

Answer (score 1):

For the image normalization in the TFLite support library, you can add the following normalization op into the image processor. For example,

```
ImageProcessor imageProcessor =
    new ImageProcessor.Builder()
        .add(ResizeOp(106, 106, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR))
        .add(new NormalizeOp(127.5, 127.5))
        .build();
```

For the details, please check out from this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/lite_support#imageprocessor_architecture).

Comment: How did you decide on the value `127.5`?

Comment: For the parameter values, please check out this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata#normalization_and_quantization_parameters).

Comment: In order to accept the answer please add the reasoning behind the `127.5`, the link you mentioned in the comment have `127.5` for MobileNet how that is the correct value for my case?

Comment: The mean and std values should be determined by the data that will be encountered with the model to reflect the image data set.

Comment: Model trained / test dataset mean = .5 and std dev = 1 in my case but plugging them to `NormalizeOp` give me incorrect prediction in compared to 127.5, 127.5. Why is that?

Comment: `0.5` in `normalized_image = test_image - 0.5` is the mean

Comment: Normalization option can be applicable when there is a normalization process in the training. I am not sure that the model is trained with the normalized inputs.

Comment: that's why I said model trained / test dataset mean = .5 and std dev = 1 but plugging them  to `NormalizeOp` give me in correct prediction but 127.5, 127.5 works fine. which is strange. I am using slightly modified version of [this script](https://github.com/jasonchang0/SoBr/blob/master/bin/convNetKerasLarge.py) have not change the the normalization specified in https://github.com/jasonchang0/SoBr/blob/master/bin/convNetKerasLarge.py#L56

Comment: Better to ask it in the another post. Maybe another model experts can help your case further.